# Recover data from unbootable android 5.0 note 3

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, adb, data-recovery, clockworkmod-recovery, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 3, which was weeks ago fully functional but had some glitches like it couldn't run games such as clash royale without an external power supply; in this case I used a power bank. After every use of apps, I would restart my phone, to prevent slow performance. Then, one time I used till the phone auto-shutdown due to low battery power, after it was charged to full I turned the power on. Unfortunately, it couldn't boot up, it was stuck in samsung logo. Now it is unbootable, though I can navigate to recovery mode but not safe mode. I want to recover data from the phone and I know one or two things about adb and CWM. Can anyone take me through step by step in order to recover data from device storage? I'd appreciate any opinions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can only boot your device into the fastboot mode and nothing else, right? Did you try OEM (Samsung) stock recovery by pressing UpVolume+Power button and had any success?

If not, then here is one way to recover your data, but you'll need one thing for this: You should have the *CWM (ClockWorkMod)* recovery image for your device, or you should be able to download it from somewhere. Assuming that you can do that, here is what you can do:

1. Boot into the fastboot prompt and connect it to your PC's USB port.
2. On the PC, ensure that ADB drivers for your device are installed correctly (If you were able to run adb/fastboot commands, that's enough).
3. Use fastboot command to temporarily boot your device using the CWM image:

   ```
   fastboot boot /path/to/CWMRecoveryImage.img
   ```
4. Once inside CWM recovery, adb will start working!
5. Just pull the files/folders you need using the adb pull command:

   ```
   adb pull /sdcard/foo/bar/myfile1.dat
   adb pull /sdcard/foo/bar/myfile2.dat
   adb pull /sdcard/foo/baz/*
   ```

Alternatively, you can use a tool like DroidExplorer in step 5 to recover your data more easily. Hope this helps.

**edit**

I found [this XDA link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2454079) where some CWM recovery images are available for the Galaxy Note series, but be careful that you select the one for your exact model.

Comment: I tried your way but surprisingly adb doesn't work while on CWM recovery. Fortunately, I found another way which uses twrp recovery.

Comment: "surprisingly adb doesn't work while on CWM recovery." - Some device specific issue? `adb` certainly worked for me on my MiPad when I booted with the CWM recovery image.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of CWM recovery, I used TWRP one. Obviously, a rooted phone is required. First, download a suitable twrp recovery from http://www.xda-developers.com/.
Then, if you don't have odin software, download the latest version of that.
Finally, flash recovery image using odin. Now, boot your phone in recovery mode and you can extract data as much as you wish.